# How do I search an array of PowerShell objects and the retrieve index to a matching string?

Tags: arrays, powershell, indexing

I need to search a custom PowerShell array of objects (which consists of data from both AD and Exchange - 5 columns: mail, dn, extensionAttribute7, TotalItemSize, Count). I gather this data daily (for each user whose total item size > specified size) and export it to an XML file using Export-Clixml so that I can reference the data in subsequent days. Each day I perform a new search for mailboxes > specified size and save data about the matching mailboxes, but I need to cross-reference my existing array of users. If the user is already in my array, then I want to increment the count attribute in my PS object by 1, otherwise I want to add the user to my array as a new PS custom object. That way I can track users whose mailboxes are consistently exceeding the specified size and act accordingly (this is a customer requirement).

The piece I am struggling with is searching my array of custom PS objects for a match in order to determine whether I need to add the user as a new object or just increment the counter for a user because they are already in my array. In the beginning I thought I could use .IndexOf or -Contains to find a match in my array but they don't appear to work on arrays containing PS Objects. The only way I have been able to get this to work is as follows:

```
#Check to see if this user is already in our master mbxlist array from previous days
$ndx = 0..($mbxlist.length - 1) | Where-Object {$mbxlist[$_].mail -eq $($m.mail)}
```

$ndx is then set to the index of the matching object in my array or is $null if there's no match. But this doesn't seem very efficient, especially when I am searching through an array of 1000s of objects for each separate user that I am checking on a daily basis. Surely there must be a better way to do this? I did think of creating a separate string array containing just the users' mail address and then using indexof to check for a match. I could infer that the matching PS object would have the same index number as my array of strings and then update the count in corresponding ps object array accordingly:

```
# Create an array of strings based on the mail attribute in my PS object array
foreach ($m in $mbxlist) {[array]$lookup += $m.mail.ToString()}

#Search the lookup array for matching email address using IndexOf
$ndx=[array]::indexof($lookup,"joe.bloggs@mydomain,com")

#If ndx > 0 I've got a match so increment the count in the corresponding PS object
If ($ndx -ge 0)
{
    $mbxlist[$ndx].Count = ($mbxlist[$ndx].Count) + 1
}
```

Would this be more efficient because IndexOf is quicker than performing a Where-Object for each user I am searching for?

I have searched and tested for days and I can't figure this out. I am relatively new to PowerShell so I am probably missing something really obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps or not, but you can try loading your objects into a hash table using the email address as the key, then reference it by that (not tested):

```
$ht = @{}
import-clixml mbxdata.xml |
 foreach {$ht[$_.mail] = $_}

$mailboxes = get-mailbox -resultsize unlimited |
  select -ExpandProperty PrimarySMTPAddress

foreach ($mbx in $mailboxes){
 if ($ht[$mbx] -eq $null)
   {
     $ht[$mbx] = new-object PSObject #Create and add new object here
   }

  if ((get-mailboxstatistics $mbx).totalitemsize -gt '<some value>')
    {
      $ht[$mbx].count ++
    }
 }

$ht.Values | export-clixml mbxdata.xml
```

Comment: Many thanks mjolinor. I think this is exactly what I was looking for. I've not really used hash tables before. Do you know if there is a performance improvement vs. just using a normal array and ::indexof to search the array? I still can't believe there isn't a built-in method or cmdlet to locate/modify custom ps object arrays.

Comment: Haven't tested, but hash table operations are very efficient, and I'd expect that to be substantially faster than any array search. You can only use a hash table if all the keys are unique, but in this application they will be.  Typically to locate an object in an array, you'd use where-object.

Comment: @stukey, just to add to mjolinor's answer, a hash table will improve search-indexing. There's an algorithm the .NET Framework uses for hashing that is used whenever you use the index ($ht[$mbx], in this case), and instead of it having to search for the item in the underlying data structure iteratively, it can reference it based on known information (almost like finding the page number for a definition in a dictionary), so it can return the data faster. One thing I'd recommend about doing this performing ALL comparisons as lower-case, though, because "Mbx" is not the same as "mbx". Just FYI

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly.  You just need to compare the previous object with the current one and pick out the differences.

You can do that with [Compare-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941.aspx), and specify the property you want to compare.

Below is an example of comparing two objects and finding the differences that exist in $object2 only.

```
  $object1 = @()
  $object2 = @()
  $FirstNames = ("Jane","James","Jen","Jim")

Foreach($fn in $FirstNames){

    $object1 += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Firstname = $fn
    LastName  = "Doe"
    }

}

$object2 += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
           Firstname = "Jimmy"
           LastName  = "Doe"
           }

$object2 += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
           Firstname = "Jane"
           LastName  = "Doe"
           }


Compare-Object $object1 $object2 -Property  'FirstName' | ? { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" }
```

And you can pipe the results to a foreach to do something based on the differences found.

```
Compare-Object $object1 $object2 -Property  'FirstName' | ? { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } | %{Write-Host $_.FirstName }
```

Also note that you might need to sort your objects before you compare them using the [Sort-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176968.aspx) cmdlet.

Comment: Many thanks for your response but unfortunately that's not what I want to do. I don't want to compare the objects. I want to see if a specific string (mail address) is already in my array of objects. If it is I want to increment the 'count' property of the matching object in the array. If it is not already in the array I want add a new PS object to my array which contains the mail address and other properties. I don't think I could do that with Compare-Object?

Comment: Based on what I understand, I think its worth looking into.  Compare-Object can also give you matches, and it outputs an object that you can iterate through to do the updates to your first object as you described.

Comment: Thanks again. I will look into the Compare-Object cmdlet.

Comment: No problem, remember to sort both objects by your email property before comparing them and if the objects have different properties, you need to specify the similar property that you want compared (ex. use -Property 'EmailAddress' if you only want that property compared between the objects).